# Can't use js.coffee via $getJSON upload params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, getjson

I need to use `JS` pass a params to the rails controller:

```
def page
  @select = Firstpage.where( :pid=>params[:par_id])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # page.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @select }
  end
end
```

The `js.coffee` code:

```
fetchselect=(val) ->
  $.getJSON('firstpages_controller.rb', par_id:val )

$('.homeNav').find('.unactive').click ->
  id = $(this).attr('id')
  fetchselect(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the coffeescript server-side? If it's being served to the client, then you should not be making direct requests to the controller - rather, you should be making a resource request which the rails server should resolve to the right controller.

To elaborate: when you're generating rails links on the server for the client, you'd probably so something to the effect of pages_path, which generates a url to the effect of "http://base_path/pages". This is pretty fundamental to rails - each object the user has access has RESTful representation, or in simpler terms there's a url to identify it. JSON representations of a resource are no different - to get a JSON, the url you pass to getJSON must be formatted the same way. As far as the client is concerned, "pages_controller" doesn't exist - it's a background detail that they have no direct access to.

Comment: but I want to get a Ajax page,not a newpage,how can I get the params?